# What does $a \propto i, i \in \{ 1, ..., 10\}$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

What does $a \propto i, i \in \{ 1, ..., 10\}=I$ mean?

Does it mean that one takes $i$, e.g. $i=1$ and then constructs more numbers by taking some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $a=ki$? One can take infinite amount of $k$ so one can construct more $a$s than there are $i$s.

Or does the above notation mean the same as $a \in kI$, so that the constant $k$ is the same for all elements $i$?

Comment: As the MathJax code `\propto` suggests, this means "directly proportional to", so $k$ is one *fixed* number common among the $a$'s and $i$'s.

Comment: @GNU I’ve not seen exactly this kind of thing before, so I don’t doubt you, but isn’t that just a complicated way to say “$a=0$”? Maybe some context would help, OP.